# PHP 5.4 registered session can’t access from next page

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to save session data in a PHP 5.4.

My `login.php` looks like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['adminUser']='userName';
$_SESSION['adminPassword']='password';

echo $_SESSION['adminUser']; // This works perfect

header('location:home.php');
```

My `home.php` looks like

```
session_start();

echo $userName=$_SESSION['adminUser'];
```

Here I am not getting echo to output anything. The script will work file in PHP 5.2

Any ideas on why this might not work in PHP 5.4 but does work in PHP 5.2?

Comment: Do the session cookies remain the same on both pages? Else enable `error_reporting` and find out.

Comment: how to enable error_reporting ? in ini file ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo $userName = $_SESSION['adminUser'];
```

But why not just do on `home.php` what you did on `login.php`:

```
echo $_SESSION['adminUser'];
```

Or maybe do this:

```
$userName = $_SESSION['adminUser'];
echo $userName;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply... I tried both. But its not working. Showing empty

Comment: after redirection, I cant retrieve the $_SESSION